# Does not implement System.IComparable.CompareTo(object)

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors

> Error 1   'Koordinates.Vieta' does not implement interface member 'System.IComparable.CompareTo(object)'

the code:

```
    public class Vieta : IComparable //error is thrown here, on "Vieta"
{
    public double x, y; 
    //constructor
    public Vieta(double a, double b)
    {
        x = a; y = b;
    }
    //read only parameter
    public double ilgis
    {
        get
        {
            return Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        }
    }

    public int CompareTo(Vieta other)
    {
        if (other == null) return 1;
        return other.ilgis.CompareTo(this.ilgis);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a compare method that takes an instance of the `Vieta` class.
The [`IComparable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx?ppud=4) interface declares a method `CompareTo(object)` (note that the parameter should of type `object`).

It is offcourse better to have a strong typed CompareTo method.  You could implement the [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) interface as well.

My suggestion would be to do that, and implement the `IComparable` interface explicitly.  Then, you'll end up with something like this:

```
public class Vieta : IComparable, IComparable<Vieta>
{

    IComparable.CompareTo( object obj )
    {

       var other = obj as Vieta;

       if( other == null ) return false;

       return CompareTo(other);

    }


    public int CompareTo( Vieta other )
    {
         // Implement your compare logic here.
    }

}
```

By implementing the `IComparable` interface explicitly, the `CompareTo(object)` method will be hidden from intellisense.  In fact, you'll only be able to call that method if you cast the class to the interface type (or if an instance of that class is passed to a method that takes an `IComparable` parameter, for instance).

Answer (score 2):

Change the class to this:

```
public class Vieta : IComparable<Vieta>
```

[`IComparable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) defines an `int CompareTo(object)` while the generic [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) defines an `int CompareTo(T)`.